# core plot areafill with this kind?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-plot

Are there any solution for this kind of fill for the core plot ? I konw that it can be filled with the color, an image .but when fill with the image ,It will be cover the xAxis majorGridLineStyle.Can anybody tell have the better solution,

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tiled image. If you need the gradient in the background, use a tall strip that can tile horizontally to make the stripes. If you don't care about the gradient, a small patch that includes both stripe colors will suffice.